# Understanding return with FOREACH Loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a for each loop that is looping through an array of data -

```
foreach ($products as $value){
            $product_id = $correlationId;
            $pid = mysql_escape_string($value['ProductId']);
            $dname = mysql_real_escape_string($value['departmentName']);
            $cname = mysql_real_escape_string($value['categoryName']);
            $pname = mysql_real_escape_string($value['productName']);
            $price = mysql_real_escape_string($value['productPrice']);
            $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($value['productQty']);          
            //Insert Product data into DB
            $insert_product = "INSERT INTO product(department_name,category_name,product_name,product_price,product_qty)VALUES('$dname','$cname','$pname','$price','$qty')";
            $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_product);
            if(mysql_insert_id() >  0){
                $response = array('CorrelationId'=>$pid,
                            'Messages'=> array('Has been added.')
                );
                return $response;
            }

        }
```

I am really looking on information to best return $response without stopping the loop. I would like it to return the data then carry back on with the loop then return the data then carry back on with the loop.

Currently It stops after the first return, obviously becasue the return is breaking it?

Can anyone shed some light for me?

Thanks

Edit - Extra Code added

```
//Create complex type for StringArray
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'StringArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')),
    'xsd:string'
);
//Create complex type for AddProductResponce
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'AddProductResponse',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'CorrelationId' => array('name'=>'CorrelationId','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'Messages' => array('name'=>'Messages','type'=>'tns:StringArray'),
    )
);
```

Im working with a NUSAOP server and thats the complexTypes to handle the responce, I cannot seem to be able to adjust these to help aid the return after the loop

Comment: append `$response` to an array, return that after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $response[] = array('CorrelationId'=>$pid,
                    'Messages'=> array('Has been added.')
        );
```

and when the loop ends reutrn it.

```
        return $response;
```

The difference is that now $response is an array of arrays.
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried this however, the data in this array needs to stay in this format, appending it will change its structure

Comment: the data's format is the same , you should change the way you're handling with the `$response` variable after the loop. Consider adding the code which handling with that variable and I'll try to customize it to the suggested format.

Comment: Shouldn't you send those 2 request for each record? if so , why even returning those value and not sending them right away?

Comment: I don't understand what you have said sorry